# 404 with tomcat / eclipse deployed webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

This is incredibly frustrating.

I have deployed a webapp to debug in Eclipse / tomcat.  I have the "Use Tomcat installation" radio button selected to use my own server.  Thats all fine.  But when I try to access my web app, I get a 404 error.  I can see that it has been deployed in the wptwebapps folder.  Logs show nothing but 404.  I can access the manager application just fine, and it shows my web app is deployed.

Ive done the clean/republish, re-add, etc...over and over. same issue.

On top of that, if I deploy the war file manually through the manager app, it deploys, and the app runs with no issue (although it deploys to 'webapps' instead of 'wptwebapps').  What could be the problem?

Comment: You deploy to a different prefix than you think so the URL is different?

Comment: if that were the case, wouldnt it also be different when it is manually deployed (causing the same problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the "Servers" tab and click-right on the "properties" and press the button "Switch Location". After that you make the test again.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project Properties` -> `Web Project Settings` and check for `Context Root`. Access your application by this name:

[image]

For example if you see there `MyProject` and your tomcat is runing on 8080, access it by `http://localhost:8080/MyProject`

Comment: I am.  Its the correct context root.  Thank you though.

Comment: If i go to http://localhost:8080,  I get the tomcat welcome page.  If I go to http://localhost:8080/appname/index.html I get 404.

Comment: but like i said, if i deploy the war manually, it works just fine

Comment: Do you really have a mapping to index.html or is index.html your welcome page? What kind of configuration do you have? Please share your project files and contents with structure.